# calc() and vh workaround for chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, viewport-units, css-calc

Is there a strictly css only workaround for using `vh` in `calc()` functions for chrome?

I need to have a browser use `calc(100vh - 25px)` for a top `margin` to sticky a 25px bar on the bottom of the page, but chrome is giving me issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you set your element's `box-sizing` property to `border-box`, you can then give it 25px padding at the bottom, then allow the 25px bar to sit on top by also giving it a negative 25px margin:

```css
elem {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

You may then need to play around with your elements' `z-index` property to ensure your 25px bar is displayed on top of the other element.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/7Uu29/1/).

The padding is used to prevent any content from appearing under our 25px bar.

```
 --------------     --------------     --------------
|              |   |              |   |              |
| 100vh        |   |  100vh       |   |  100vh       |
|              |   |              |   |              |
|              |   |--------------|   |--------------| 25px padding, -25px margin
|              |   | 25px padding |   | 25px bar     |
 --------------     --------------     --------------
| 25px bar     |   | 25px bar     |
 --------------     --------------
```